# How to pass rails route as parameter to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to pass a rails route as parameter to controller as variable, so the Back button knows where to back. Tried to include :previous_page => route_path as parameter for link_to. However it caused an error in index page display.

```
  def edit_cust?(cust, previous_page)
    return link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(cust, :previous_page => previous_page) if has_edit_right?(cust)
  end
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could paste the code that you are trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
link_to "back", :back
```

Comment: :back does not serve the purpose. :back can only back to previous view page and form a dead loop.